# Merge columns of two CSV files in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, csv, datagridview, merge

I've been working in a project that needs to import two .CSV file and merge it.
I've used `CachedCsvReader` and `StreamReader` to import the CSV1 and CSV2 file in `dataGridView1` and `dataGridView2` and it works perfectly. Now I need two merge these two dataGridView or the CSV files in `dataGridView3`. I've tried many different techniques throughout the web to solve it but nothing works.
For example, I've used `Excel.Application`,Workbook and Worksheet things to solve it and also the dataGridView methods but nothing works. Can anyone Please help me?!! It would be really Appreciated!! By the way, the header of each column is written below the header name like A, B, C, the names are below them in the first (1) row.

For your convenience, I'm adding the small part that I've done so far below,

```
using (CachedCsvReader csv1 = new CachedCsvReader(new StreamReader(textBox1.Text), true))
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = csv1;
}
```

After the suggestion of Mr. Damith I did this:

```
OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(textBox1.Text) +"; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");
         conn1.Open();
         OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text), conn1);
         DataSet ds1 = new DataSet("Temp"); 
         adapter1.Fill(ds1);
        // you can get datatable as bellow 
         DataTable tb1 = ds1.Tables[0];

         OleDbConnection conn2 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(textBox2.Text) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");
         conn2.Open();
         OleDbDataAdapter adapter2 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(textBox2.Text), conn2);
         DataSet ds2 = new DataSet("Temp");
         adapter2.Fill(ds2);
         // you can get datatable as bellow 
         DataTable tb2 = ds2.Tables[0];

        //Merge
         tb1.Merge(tb2);

        //View dataGridView 3
         dataGridView3.DataSource = tb1;
         dataGridView3.Update();
```

Now with the content, click the link below to download the Text file of the example.
[Click here to download the .txt file](http://www.adrive.com/public/AcvH2U/example.txt)

I hope this might help you.
Thanks!
-Saffan.

Comment: Please update the question with columns in csv files and what you expect after merge

Comment: I've added a link of a .txt file that contains the example. I hope it'll work, thanks!

Comment: since you have different schema you can't use merge. check http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37444/Full-Outer-Join-of-Two-DataTables-C-Code, it will help you to merge tables.

Comment: you can try Altova Mapforce for merging CSV files.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! Just tell me one thing, if I need to access a coulmn's header and the contents of that column (a cell will also work), what do I have to do?

Comment: I don't know how to use Altova Mapforce. Any example? @sarooptrivedi.

Comment: Altova Mapforce is third party tool. In this you can directly mapping your two CSV file. That tool automatically generate the code. as per your custom mapping design.

Comment: http://www.altova.com/mapforce.html

Comment: But at here the CSV files are not fixed. User can select any CSV file using OpenDialogBox.

Comment: This mapForce can't read CSV files. Any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I outsourced the task and he used LINQ to do the merge.

Answer (score 0):

If mapping is difficult, you can always build the needed columns and iterate through the CSV file and add each cell manually, it won't take much coding.

Loop CSV1 add data to proper cells.
Loop CSV2 add data to proper cells.